# Tkinter Toplevel window not appearing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Python 3.8, Win 10 is the os, Toplevel widget does not appear to be working with new window not appearing.  Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def popup():
   top = Toplevel(root)
   my_label_top = Label(top, text="This is a Tkinter Popup")
   top.mainloop()


my_button = Button(root, text="Popup, click here", command="popup")
my_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: remove quotations from the command. Make it `popup` not `"popup".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

- The only issue here is that the callback `command` shouldn't be a string.

**Solution:**

- Remove the quotes around `popup` and the `Toplevel` window should appear.

**Fixed Code:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def popup():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    my_label_top = Label(top, text="This is a Tkinter Popup")
    my_label_top.pack()


my_button = Button(root, text="Popup, click here", command=popup)
my_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**Tips:**

- Using `top.mainloop()` is not necessary.
- You also forgot to `pack()` the `Label`(`my_label_top`)